# Triggering a transition mid-animation CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

Been trying to trigger a transition using `:hover` in a running animation using CSS, in the example below, only the `background-color` changes on `:hover` but the `transform` property is triggered only after an animation stops. How can I trigger the `transform: rotate` during the animation?

Also, my initial `background-color: red` seems to fade-in when I reload the page without me explicitly triggering it by `:hover`. I assume it's caused by the `transition-duration`, can this be avoided using only CSS?

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: animation;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  transition-duration: 5s;
  transition-property: all;
}

.red:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  background-color: teal;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforms do not stack in this way. One way to work around this limitation could be to use a parent element for the rotation transform.

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: animation;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  transition-duration: 5s;
  transition-property: all;
}

.red:hover {
  background-color: teal;
}

.wrap {
  transition: all 5s;
}

.wrap:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried your solution myself before posting the question and it worked, I was just wondering if I can do it without the parent element.

Comment: What about the background color fade-in when I load the page, can I get rid of it so the .red div shows instantly?

Comment: I don't believe there is any other way to use multiple transforms in this scenario. I'm not sure what you mean by "the background color fade-in when I load the page". The red square should be visible instantly.

Comment: I use chrome, when reload the page the .red div takes exactly 5 seconds to slowly appear on the page from invisible to fully visible, if i remove the transition-duration: 5s; then it appears instantly. But in this case I lose the slow transition back from teal color to red when I remove my cursor from the .red div.

Comment: That is what you see in the example above? Or on your own webpage?

Comment: It was present with my code, the first one that I posted, then I copied your answer, and the "fade-in" effect is still there.

Comment: I think you must have other CSS on your page that is causing this. There is nothing in the code above that would cause _anything_ to fade in or out. When you click the "Run code snippet" button does the div fade in?

Comment: No, when I run the snippet it just appears there. This is why I'm annoyed, I can't find the reason, i checked and there are no other CSS that could cause this.

Comment: There has to be. Use your browsers developer tools, right-click the square, choose "Inspect Element". Look through the styles until you find the culprit. Check parent elements too. Unless you can produce a [MRE] showing the issue it isn't really possible for anyone to help find the specific styles.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try. Will post if I find the reason.

Comment: I have posted a new question with this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658299/transition-starting-on-page-load-for-some-reason