# Transition starting on page load for some reason

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

**Update:** when I put the CSS internally, the problem goes away. I went in the dev tools on my chrome and compared what was happening when I reloaded the page. First image is with internal CSS, the second one is with external stylesheet, you can see different results for the `background-color` property:

[image]
[image]

**Initial post:** I have no idea why this is happening, here's a [demonstration](https://gyazo.com/2f2ab7caa4f6769982df3650a0e6bf77). Basically, the `a` takes some time to appear fully on the page.

The time it takes to 'fully' appear is the same duration specified in `transition: background 5s;` as in 5 seconds.

Here's the same code on another [page](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=css-smooth-transition-of-link-background-color-on-mouse-hover) where the effect is not observed, I also opened it in the same browser.

Here's my code in Visual Studio and in Chrome, the same behavior is observed in Edge but not in Firefox, in Firefox it just loads as it should and the `:hover` effects work properly. All 3 browsers are updated to their latest versions at the time of writing.

This only happens when I link to an external CSS stylesheet. When I copy the css to the html file the problem goes away!!!

[image]
[image]

CSS

```
a {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  font: bold 18px sans-serif;
  background: #fd7c2a;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background 5s; /* For Safari 3.0 to 6.0 */
  transition: background 5s; /* For modern browsers */
}

a:hover {
  background: #3cc16e;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <!-- Specifies a description of the page. Search engines can pick up this description to show with the results of searches -->
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!-- Specifies a comma-separated list of keywords - relevant to the page -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p><a href="#">Hover on me</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tested on chrome (downloaded the html file you shared) and it seems to be fine, are you sure there are no other elements?

Comment: pretty sure, dont know what im missing if you say that it works fine. I've been banging my head against the wall for the last couple of hours trying to solve this and nothing.

Comment: This only happens when I link to an external CSS stylesheet. When I copy the css to the html file the problem goes away!!!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any browser extension which could mess up with the css? Maybe try testing this in a private tab.

Comment: Can you show the complete style sheet? I have tested the excerpts by turning them into an inline code snippet and it worked fine.

Comment: @collapsar: this is the complete stylesheet, I was just testing the transition effect.

Comment: @J'hack le lezard: well it didnt happen before, and i have not installed new extensions before the problem started

Comment: I have updated my post, when I make the CSS internal, the problem goes away and theres is a difference in what is shown inside the chrome dev tools when i use internal and external stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, been going through google for answers. The solution is to add `<script> </script>` opening and closing tags in the html file separated by space. Apparently its a bug in the browsers mentioned before.